# Terraform reports error "Failed to query available provider packages"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have created main.tf file as below for Mongodb terraform module.

```
resource "mongodbatlas_teams" "test" {
  org_id     = null
  name       = "MVPAdmin_Team"
  usernames  = ["user1@email.com", "user2@email.com", "user3@email.com"]
}

resource "mongodbatlas_project" "test" {
  name   = "MVP_Project"
  org_id = null

  teams {
    team_id    = null
    role_names = ["GROUP_CLUSTER_MANAGER"]

  }
  
}
resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list" "test" {
  project_id = null
  ip_address = null
  comment    = "IP address for MVP Dev cluster testing"
}

resource "mongodbatlas_cluster" "test" {
  name                = "MVP_DevCluster"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  cluster_type        = REPLICASET
  state_name          = var.state_name
  replication specs {
     num_shards= var.num_shards
     region_config {
       region_name = "AU-EA"
       electable_nodes = var.electable_nodes
       priority        = var.priority
       read_only_nodes = var.read_only_nodes
     }  
  }

  provider_backup_enabled = var.provider_backup_enabled
  auto_scaling_disk_gb_enabled = var.auto_scaling_disk_gb_enabled
  mongo_db_major_version = var.mongo_db_major_version
  provider_name = "Azure"
  provider_disk_type_name = var.provider_disk_type_name
  provider_instance_size_name = var.provider_instance_size_name



  mongodbatlas_database_user {
    username = var.username
    password = var.password
    auth_database_name = var.auth_database_name
    role_name = var.role_name
    database_name = var.database_name
  }
  mongodbatlas_database_snapshot_backup_policy {
    policy_item = var.policy_item
    frequency_type = var.frequency_type
    retention_value = var.retention_value
  
 }

 advanced_configuration {
      minimum_enabled_tls_protocol = var.minimum_enabled_tls_protocol
   no_table_scan                  = var.no_table_scan
   connection_string              = var.connection_string

 } 
}
```

However, **terraform init** reports as below:

```
$ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/mongodbatlas...

Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
hashicorp/mongodbatlas: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have
a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/mongodbatlas

If you have just upgraded directly from Terraform v0.12 to Terraform v0.14
then please upgrade to Terraform v0.13 first and follow the upgrade guide for
that release, which might help you address this problem.

Did you intend to use mongodb/mongodbatlas? If so, you must specify that
source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which
modules are currently depending on hashicorp/mongodbatlas, run the following
command:
    terraform providers
```

Any idea as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you recently moved from one version of Terraform to a newer one? Try adding something like this to your tf file(s): https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mongodb/mongodbatlas/latest/docs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message explains the most likely reason for seeing this error message: you've upgraded directly from Terraform v0.12 to Terraform v0.14 without running through [the Terraform v0.13 upgrade steps](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-13.html).

If you upgrade to Terraform v0.13 first and follow those instructions then the upgrade tool should be able to give more specific instructions on what to change here, and may even be able to automatically upgrade your configuration for you.

However, if you wish then you can alternatively manually add the configuration block that the v0.13 upgrade tool would've inserted, to specify that you intend to use the `mongodb/mongodbatlas` provider as "mongodbatlas" in this module:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    mongodbatlas = {
      source = "mongodb/mongodbatlas"
    }
  }
}
```

There are some other considerations in the v0.13 upgrade guide that the above doesn't address, so you may still need to perform the steps described in that upgrade guide if you see different error messages after trying what I showed above.

Comment: Apologies mate but I did not change TF Version. I shall certainly try your suggestion. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just a friendly notice: you have a typo in monogdb/mongodbatlas It should be: source = "mongodb/mongodbatlas"

Answer (score 0):

To install **aws** provider, copy and paste this code into your Terraform configuration. Then, run **terraform init**.
Terraform 0.13+

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.60.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i know how explain it. need open web «https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json» . after init comannd is working (plus i make ipconfig /flushdns)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).